# how i can merge multi pdfs files by using VBA code

Tags: ms-access, vba, pdftk

I have a table that contains a paths  of multi pdfs file...now I need a VBA code to merge  all these files to a single pdf file.
Notice:-the number of pdfs files to be merged varies from time to time.

```
Sub Combine_PDFs_Demo()
Dim i As Integer 'counter for records
Dim x As Integer
Dim strNPDF As String
Dim bSuccess As Boolean
Dim DB As Database
Dim RS As Recordset
Set DB = CurrentDb
Set RS = DB.OpenRecordset("SELECT[paths] from scantemp ")
strNPDF = CurrentProject.Path & "\request_pic\" & (request_no) & ".pdf"
RS.MoveLast
DB.Recordsets.Refresh
i = RS.RecordCount
RS.MoveFirst
Dim strPDFs() As String
ReDim strPDFs(0 To i)
strPDFs(0) = RS![paths]
RS.MoveNext
For i = 1 To i - 1
strPDFs(i) = RS![paths]
bSuccess = MergePDFs(strPDFs, strNPDF)
Next i
If bSuccess = False Then MsgBox "Failed to combine all PDFs", vbCritical, "Failed to Merge PDFs"
DoCmd.SetWarnings False
DoCmd.RunSQL "delete from scantemp" 'delete all paths from table scantemp after converted it to pdf
DoCmd.SetWarnings True
  RS.Close
    Set RS = Nothing`enter code here`
```

Comment: What code do you have right now? You must have a loop that retrieves the PDF file paths? Take that loop and add a command line utility like `pdftk`. Not a great first question if you come expecting someone to write your code for you

Comment: And what is *MergePDFs*? Please describe the problem: error or undesired result? And please indent code for readability.

Comment: I've used GhostScript for this; works beautifully. It'll merge PDF's for you.

Comment: `CreateObject("AcroExch.PDDoc")`  always gives me "No such interface supported" I have Adobe Acrobat DC installed

Answer (score 2):

```
public Function MergePDFs(arrFiles() As String, strSaveAs As String) As Boolean
Dim objCAcroPDDocDestination As Acrobat.CAcroPDDoc
Dim objCAcroPDDocSource As Acrobat.CAcroPDDoc
Dim i As Integer
Dim iFailed As Integer

On Error GoTo NoAcrobat:
'Initialize the Acrobat objects
Set objCAcroPDDocDestination = CreateObject("AcroExch.PDDoc")
Set objCAcroPDDocSource = CreateObject("AcroExch.PDDoc")
 'Open Destination, all other documents will be added to this and saved with
'a new filename
objCAcroPDDocDestination.Open (arrFiles(LBound(arrFiles))) 'open the first file
 'Open each subsequent PDF that you want to add to the original
  'Open the source document that will be added to the destination
    For i = LBound(arrFiles) + 1 To UBound(arrFiles)
        objCAcroPDDocSource.Open (arrFiles(i))
        If objCAcroPDDocDestination.InsertPages(objCAcroPDDocDestination.GetNumPages - 1, objCAcroPDDocSource, 0, objCAcroPDDocSource.GetNumPages, 0) Then
          MergePDFs = True
        Else
          'failed to merge one of the PDFs
          iFailed = iFailed + 1
        End If
        objCAcroPDDocSource.Close
    Next i
objCAcroPDDocDestination.save 1, strSaveAs 'Save it as a new name
objCAcroPDDocDestination.Close
Set objCAcroPDDocSource = Nothing
Set objCAcroPDDocDestination = Nothing

NoAcrobat:
If iFailed <> 0 Then
    MergePDFs = False
End If
On Error GoTo 0
End Function
```

Comment: You're assuming someone has subscribed to and installed Adobe Acrobat Exchange?

Answer (score 1):

This uses a list of PDF or PS files to create one PDF. Sorry it's in VB.net and I don't really have time to convert. But it illustrates the concept if you can wade through it. Basically you write the options and file names to a text file then use that file as an argument to Ghostscript.

```
    Private Shared Sub ConvertToPDF(ByVal PSPathFileList As List(Of String), _
                             ByVal PDFPathName As String, _
                             ByVal WaitForExit As Boolean, ByVal DeletePS As Boolean)

        'check that all files exist
        PSPathFileList.ForEach(AddressOf CheckFiles)

        'check old pdf file
        If IO.File.Exists(PDFPathName) Then
            Throw New ApplicationException( _
                "PDF cannot be created. File already exists: " & PDFPathName)
        End If

        'convert engine
        Dim myProcInfo As New ProcessStartInfo
        myProcInfo.FileName = DanBSolutionsLocation & "Misc\GhostScript\GSWIN32C.EXE"
        Debug.Print(myProcInfo.FileName)

        'write file names to text file as the list can be very long
        Dim tempPath As String = IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(PSPathFileList.Item(0))
        Dim fiName2 As String = tempPath & IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(PDFPathName) & ".txt"

        Dim ft As New StreamWriter(fiName2)
        ft.WriteLine("-sDEVICE=pdfwrite -q -dSAFER -dNOPAUSE -sOUTPUTFILE=""" & PDFPathName & """ -dBATCH ")
        For i As Long = 0 To PSPathFileList.Count - 1
            ft.WriteLine(Chr(34) & PSPathFileList.Item(i) & Chr(34))
        Next
        ft.Close()

        'set args to text file
        myProcInfo.Arguments = """@" & fiName2 & """"

        'set up for output and errors
        myProcInfo.UseShellExecute = False
        myProcInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = True
        myProcInfo.RedirectStandardError = True
        Debug.Print(myProcInfo.Arguments)

        'do the conversion
        Dim myProc As Process = Process.Start(myProcInfo)

        Debug.Print(myProc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd)
        Debug.Print(myProc.StandardError.ReadToEnd)

        If WaitForExit Then
            'wait for finish; (no more than 60 seconds)
            myProc.WaitForExit(60000)

            'delete PS
            If DeletePS Then
                PSPathFileList.ForEach(AddressOf DeleteFiles)
            End If
        End If

    End Sub
```

Here's VBA code for a single PS to PDF. So between the VB.net above and this below hopefully you can salvage something useful.

```
Private Sub printToPdfDemo()

    'verify printer setup
    'be sure to install the PsPrinterInstall module
    Call PSPrinterSetup

    Dim svPsFileName As String
    Dim svPDFName As String

    'define names
    svPsFileName = "C:\Temp\Input 1.ps"
    svPDFName = "C:\Temp\Output 1.PDF"

    'save current printer
    Dim PrinterInUse As String
    PrinterInUse = Application.ActivePrinter

    'print to PS
    'If Fso.FileExists(svPsFileName) Then Call Fso.DeleteFile(svPsFileName)
    Worksheets(1).PrintOut ActivePrinter:=PSPrinterName, PrintToFile:=True, _
        PrToFileName:=svPsFileName

    'revert to saved printer name
    Application.ActivePrinter = PrinterInUse

    'convert
    Call ConvertToPDF(svPsFileName, svPDFName)
End Sub


Sub ConvertToPDF(ByVal svPsFileName As String, ByVal svPDFName As String)
    Dim fso As New FileSystemObject
    'Dim Fso: Set Fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Dim folGS As Folder
    Dim lcCmd As String

    'check inputs
    If svPsFileName = "" Or svPDFName = "" Then
        Call MsgBox("PS file name or PDF file name is blank in ""ConvertToPDF"" macro", vbExclamation, "Error! Missing Inputs")
        Exit Sub
    End If

    'check file
    If Not fso.FileExists(svPsFileName) Then
        Call MsgBox(svPsFileName & " file is not found", vbExclamation, "Error! Missing File")
        Exit Sub
    End If

    'check variable
    If DanBSolutionsLocation = "" Then DanBSolutionsLocation = GetDanBSolutionsLocation

    'delete old file
    If fso.FileExists(svPDFName) Then Call fso.DeleteFile(svPDFName)

    'get files
    Set folGS = fso.GetFolder(DanBSolutionsLocation & "Misc\GhostScript\") 'S:\DanB Solutions\Misc\GhostScript\GSWIN32C.EXE

    'GS command
    lcCmd = folGS.ShortPath & "\GSWIN32C.EXE " & _
    "-q -dNOPAUSE -I" & folGS.ShortPath & "\lib;./fonts " & _
    "-sFONTPATH=./fonts -sFONTMAP=" & folGS.ShortPath & "\lib\FONTMAP.GS " & _
    "-sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOUTPUTFILE=" & """" & svPDFName & """" _
    & " -dBATCH " & """" & svPsFileName & """"

    'convert
    Debug.Print lcCmd
    Call ShellWait(lcCmd)

    'delete PS
    If fso.FileExists(svPDFName) Then fso.DeleteFile (svPsFileName)

End Sub
```