# Automate saving PDFs opened in web browser into specified folder in directory and merge into one

Tags: python, html, vba, ms-access, pdf

I have never done any sort of javscript/html/batch scripting or anything like that before. I have used VBA with MS Access quite extensively but I have a problem that I cannot use my skills for.

**Required:**
Several different PDFs that are opened in a web browser to be saved and(/then) merged into one document.

**Background:**
I have an access database that contains a list of parts, equipment and its related documents (certificates/datasheets etc). The actual datasheets are stored in a company file management system that requires you to check documents in and out. HOWEVER, I found a way of opening a pdf document (stored in this system) in a web browser. My current MS Access script can select which documents to open depending on certain conditions selected in the database and it does so automatically. After this is where I am having problems.

**Problem:**
The approach I would like to take is to save all of the opened documents in a directory and then merge all files in that directory into one pdf.

I have tagged Python, HTML and VBA because I'm unsure what I should be using to try and find my problem. I'm aso stuck on ideas on how to start or whether this is even possible without third-party software I have to pay for.

I have tried a partial solution where I open the pdf file in a web browser control in MS Access and then use the following to print. This works on actual web browsers (Testing with google.com) but as my documents are not webpages this partial solution doesn't work.

```
Dim objIE As Object
Set objIE = Me.WebBrowser2.object
objIE.ExecWB OLECMDID_PRINT, OLECMDEXECOPT_DONTPROMPTUSER
```

I've created a htm file and managed to have the webpage to print on open using the following but again I'm unsure how to transfer these to my application.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
      window.onload = function() { window.print(); }
 </script>
```

I have had no success in finding ideas on google, especially one I can follow as a beginner. Any and all suggestions or solutions will be appreciated.

**EDIT**
Added code used to open the PDF's in the browser.

The following is the specific line that opens the link, however below it is the section of the code that it is used in.

```
CreateObject("Shell.Application").Open "http://trimconnect/SP/view/" & trimnumber(i)
```

Larger code snippet:

```
eqpID = Forms!frmequipment!ID
trimnumber = ""

Set dbs = CurrentDb
Set rst_ID = dbs.OpenRecordset("SELECT tblEqpDocuments.docID FROM tblEqpDocuments WHERE tblEqpDocuments.eqpID = " & eqpID, dbOpenSnapshot)

'Store values of query (document IDs) into multi-dimensional array
docIdArray = rst_ID.GetRows(99999)

'loop through array values and open link for each array
For i = 0 To UBound(docIdArray, 2)
    qryTrim = "SELECT tblDocuments.Trim FROM tblDocuments WHERE (tblDocuments.ID = " & docIdArray(0, i) & ")"
    Set rst_Trim = dbs.OpenRecordset(qryTrim, dbOpenSnapshot)
    trimnumber = trimnumber & "," & rst_Trim.Fields("trim").Value
Next i

If trimnumber = "" Then
    MsgBox "There are no related documents available to print."
Else
    'Store trim link string into an array
    trimnumber = Split(trimnumber, ",")
    
    For i = 1 To UBound(trimnumber)

    'Open the links
    CreateObject("Shell.Application").Open "http://trimconnect/SP/view/" & trimnumber(i)
        
    Next i
End If
```

Comment: Would help to include the code you use to open the PDF's in the browser.

Comment: @TimWilliams thanks Tim, I've added that now.

Comment: Your question lacks focus. Exactly what is the issue? How to print PDF? How to copy to another folder? How to merge? Each of those topics should be its own posted question. I have VBA code that merges PDFs but it requires having AcrobatPro installed. It isn't necessary to copy PDFs to another directory to merge them into a new PDF file. Programmatically merging PDF files is a fairly common topic.

Comment: If you open that URL in (eg) Acrobat does it open a PDF, or does it open an HTML page which contains a PDF?  You might be able to download the PDF's directly to disc.  Merging them into a single document is another story.

Comment: @TimWilliams it opens an HTML page which contains a PDF. Yeah my thinking is that once these are open I can write code (just not sure VBA/Python/etc which would be best) to save them all directly to a folder in a directory. Not sure how to go about this though.

Comment: If you have "***pdf document (stored in this system)***", why is it opening in browser and not Adobe? Why open at all if goal is to merge files?

Comment: @June7 I included extra information for context. The issue is that I want to merge a bunch of PDFs that are opened on a web page. I provided some ideas I had but they were just to show that I had put thought into it. 

The root issue is that I want to merge PDFs into one PDF. However these PDFs are opened via a hyperlink and opened on a web browser (html page).

Comment: Again, why must they be opened to web page? User selects file(s) and code merges. Why the intermediate step of opening? Common topic, start with review of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50298884/how-i-can-merge-multi-pdfs-files-by-using-vba-code

Comment: @June7 The system is called content manager, files are stored on a server somewhere, to open the file you need to check in and out, but if you use the hyperlink, you end up opening the pdf in a html page. Its a temporary copy, once you close the page you lose the page unless you use that link again. Its not actually stored locally, which is why I want to save as pdf since im assuming you cant merge files that are not yet saved locally.

Comment: @June7 it doesn't have to be saved to a webpage, im not specifically telling it to open as a webpage.. its just how it opens. Happy to be shown how I can open it directly into adobe.

Comment: That helps my understanding. Review https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/how-to-save-pdf-opened-in-an-ie-page-thru-vba.724739/

Comment: @June7 brilliant thanks, will look into that now

Comment: I don't know if merge code could work directly with the URL - maybe could. As to opening in web browser instead of Adobe - do you have system default app for PDF files set for Adobe?

Comment: @June7 Yep system default app for .pdf set for adobe

Comment: @June7 you know when you click on a link on a website that is for a pdf download or something, it opens it up in web browser until you save as, and then open it from your windows explorer, then it opens up in adobe or whatever else you've set your default to. I think its a similar type of link